# autoref uses wrong name for section, if label occurs after figure

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

I have a document where labels occur inside of sections, i.e., not only at the beginning of a section. If the section contains environments, then `autoref` wronlgy uses for all following labels the name of this environment, but still uses the correct numbering of the section. Moving the label definitions to the top of the section is not an option in my setup. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{ABC}
\section{DEF}
\label{sec:DEFup}

Correctly is section 2: \autoref{sec:DEFup}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  XXX
  \caption{Three X's}
\end{figure}

\label{sec:DEFdown}
\noindent
Should be section 2, but is Figure 2, which does not even exist:
\autoref{sec:DEFdown}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I recommend to insert labels exactly after the item which it is related to. So use `\label{}` after the `\section{}` or after the `\caption{}`.

Comment: A label far from a place where a counter is stepped should be used only with `\pageref`

Comment: i think this can be fixed by inserting `\phantomsection` just before the second `\label`.

Comment: `\phantomsection` did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The behavior you describe as erroneous is, in fact, entirely correct according to the hyperref syntax rules: the argument of a `\label` command is "attached" to the *most recently encountered entity* that can receive a label.

In your example, the second `\label` command is encountered after a `figure` environment is set up and is given a `caption`. Thus, the `hyperref` package (which provides the `autoref` command) must assign the label `sec:DEFdown` to the `figure` environment. The fact that the label string in the example contains the substring "sec:" does not affect the element to which it will be assigned.

The uptake:

- *Always* aim to issue `\label` directives immediately following the associated sectioning or captioning command. Keep in mind that environments such as `equation`s can also be assigned `\label`s for cross-referencing purposes.
- In the case of floats such as figures and tables, be sure to provide the `\label` command *before* the float environment ends -- but also, of course, after the float's `\caption` command is issued.

Comment: I'm not sure the behavior is _entirely_ correct... if it were shouldn't the `\autoref{sec:DEFdown}` in the example give »Figure 1« instead of »Figure 2«?

Comment: @cgnieder - If the second `\label` instruction were contained inside the `figure` environment -- which is something I believe we can all agree should be done anyway -- then `\autoref{sec:DEFdown}` would indeed generate "Figure 1" rather than "Figure 2". The problem arises because the OP has placed the second `\label` command *after* `\end{figure}`, leading autoref astray. Whether it's possible (or even desirable) to make autoref robust to such behavior by users is something I won't even attempt to answer...

Comment: agreed that the label _should_ be placed immediately after `\section` or `\caption` _or_ only be referenced with `\pageref` and I'm aware why the problem arises... but I still believe that the result »Figure 2« is at least unexpected. But it's probably not worth changing `\autoref` because of this.

Comment: This may break if there is a `\todo` in a caption, and the corresponding label right after.

Comment: @kmundnic - To be clear: LaTeX does *not* associate the argument of `\label` with any random counter which happens to have been incremented most recently. The incrementing has to occur via a `\refstepcounter` instruction. So, unless the `\todo` code contains a loop and is hacked by somebody to act in particularly devious manner, to use `\refstepcounter{<some counter>}` instead of `\stepcounter{<some counter>}`, your concern probably doesn't apply. If you'd like to explore this subject in more detail, please go ahead and raise it by posting a new query.